# write the elements of list to file

Tags: python, file

Bigram is a list which looks like-

```
[('a', 'b'), ('b', 'b'), ('b', 'b'), ('b', 'c'), ('c', 'c'), ('c', 'c'), ('c', 'd'), ('d', 'd'), ('d', 'e')]
```

Now I am trying to wrote each element if the list as a separate line in a file with this code-

```
 bigram = list(nltk.bigrams(s.split()))
 outfile1.write("%s" % ''.join(ele) for ele in bigram)
```

but I am getting this error :

> TypeError: write() argument must be str, not generator

I want the result as in file-

```
('a', 'b') 
('b', 'b')
('b', 'b')
('b', 'c')
('c', 'c')
......
```

Comment: You can't write a generator. Can you show us how you are writing (more code in your function) and what you want as desired output?

Comment: @jpp I have made the changes

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you're passing a generator comprehension to `write`, which needs strings.

If I understand correctly you want to write one representation of tuple per line.

You can achieve that with:

```
outfile1.write("".join('{}\n'.format(ele) for ele in bigram))
```

or

```
outfile1.writelines('{}\n'.format(ele) for ele in bigram)
```

the second version passes a generator comprehension to `writelines`, which avoids to create the big string in memory before writing to it (and looks more like your attempt)

it produces a file with this content:

```
('a', 'b')
('b', 'b')
('b', 'b')
('b', 'c')
('c', 'c')
('c', 'c')
('c', 'd')
('d', 'd')
('d', 'e')
```

Comment: I specifically looked up the documentation of [`writelines`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/io.html#io.IOBase.writelines) and used a list comprehension first because it says "Write a list of lines to the stream". Good to know it also works with generators but I guess it should actually say "an iterable of lines"...

Comment: yeah, it works with any iterable because it processes line after line, doesn't need the whole list beforehand.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
outfile1.writelines("{}\n".format(ele) for ele in bigram)
```

Comment: OP has edited question in the meanwhile. Your code produces lines like aa, ab, ... not the tuple representations. Besides, code without any explanation isn't very useful...

Answer (score 1):

This is the operator precedence problem.

You want an expression like this:

```
("%s" % ''.join(ele)) for ele in bigram
```

Instead, you get it interpreted like this, where the part in the parens is indeed a generator:

```
"%s" % (''.join(ele) for ele in bigram)
```

Use the explicit parentheses.

Please note that `("%s" % ''.join(ele)) for ele in bigram` is *itself* a generator. You need to call `write` on each element from it.

If you want to write each pair in a separate line, you have to add line separators explicitly. The easiest, to my mind, is an explicit loop:

```
for pair in bigram:
  outfile.write("(%s, %s)\n" % pair)
```

Comment: when I open the file it is showing <generator object <genexpr> at 0x0000023CBC1B9990>

Comment: Updated the answer.